# Connections blocked between 2 servers at the same ISP - my fault or hosting company's?

Tags: networking

I have 2 dedicated servers at ionos.com, and old one I am trying to abandon and a new one I am trying to migrate to.

In the process of migrating, I discovered that I am unable to connect between the two servers to migrate data. While the old server seems to be fine, connecting in and out of the new server is limited. while I can connect from and to the new server outside the ionos network, I cannot connect from or to the new server when both parts are in the ionos network. Despite firewalls being down (on the machines that I can control) and the relevant ports are being open (on the ionos cloud panel), I cannot wget, ssh, rsync on any port inbetween the two machines at ionos or ionos.com (for e.g. wget).

I contacted tech support at the ionos but they insist that the problem is on my side. I cannot figure out what it could be though.

So here is the detail:

When I try to access my new server from my old server, I get some or the other form of "no route to host". I can do a 'wget ionos.com', that works on my old server. When I do a 'wget mydomain.com' which is hosted on the new server, it resolves to the correct IP address, but eventually fails with 'failed: Connection timed out.'. Note that I CAN access that domain from a server outside the ionos.com network, and it works just fine.

On my new server, I can access only machines that seem to be outside of the ionos.com network. I cannot do a 'wget ionos.com', it results in a 'failed: No route to host.'. Doing a 'wget google.com' works fine. I cannot ssh or rsync to my old server. So it seems to me that my new server is somehow insulated from all other servers within the ionos.com network?

They sent me this URL to test my connection: https://www.ionos.com/help/server-cloud-infrastructure/troubleshooting/information-needed-for-networking-tickets/?utm_source=search&utm_medium=global&utm_term=networking&utm_campaign=HELP_CENTER&utm_content=/help/#c227520

On the new server, running mtr looks like this:

```
# mtr -bw -T <ip old server>
Start: 2024-03-27T14:04:53+0800
HOST: host                           Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- host.mydomain.com (<ip new server>)  0.0%    10    0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0
```

Should there be only one step? doing it to ionos.com returns almost the same:

```
# mtr -bw ionos.com
Start: 2024-03-27T14:07:45+0800
HOST: host                           Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- host.mydomain.com (<ip new server>) 10.0%    10  1789. 1899. 666.3 3078. 853.4

 mtr -bw -T google.com
Start: 2024-03-27T14:06:21+0800
HOST: host                                              Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- 10.255.255.2                                       0.0%    10    0.3   0.7   0.3   1.0   0.3
  2.|-- 104.219.43.69                                      0.0%    10    1.0   1.0   0.8   1.3   0.1
        104.219.43.70
  3.|-- ae-1.bb-b.ud.mkc.us.net.ionos.com (74.208.1.97)    0.0%    10    2.0   1.4   1.1   2.0   0.4
        ae-1.bb-b.slr.lxa.us.net.ionos.com (74.208.1.98)
        ae-2.bb-b.ud.mkc.us.net.ionos.com (74.208.1.226)
        ae-2.bb-b.slr.lxa.us.net.ionos.com (74.208.1.225)
        ae-12-0.bb-a.ga.mkc.us.net.ionos.com (74.208.1.111)
        ae-10-0.bb-a.ga.mkc.us.net.ionos.com (74.208.1.237)
  4.|-- ae-5-0.bb-a.cr.chi.us.net.ionos.com (74.208.1.67)  0.0%    10   13.4  13.5  12.9  14.0   0.3
        ae-1.bb-b.ud.mkc.us.net.ionos.com (74.208.1.97)
        ae-3.bb-b.ud.mkc.us.oneandone.net (74.208.6.193)
  5.|-- ae-5-0.bb-a.cr.chi.us.net.ionos.com (74.208.1.67)  0.0%    10   13.0  14.5  12.9  21.3   2.7
        142.250.172.186
  6.|-- 142.250.172.186                                    0.0%    10   13.2  13.3  12.9  13.6   0.2
        74.125.251.149
  7.|-- 74.125.251.149                                     0.0%    10   13.7  14.0  13.0  14.8   0.5
        74.125.251.147
        142.251.60.21
  8.|-- ord38s33-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.32.14)          0.0%    10   13.2  13.4  13.2  14.0   0.2
        142.251.60.21
```

That looks fine to me.

On on the old server, I do this:

```
# iperf3 -c us.1sys1.com -P 4
iperf3: error - unable to receive control message: Connection reset by peer

# iperf3 -c us.1sys1.com -P 4 -R
iperf3: error - unable to receive control message: Connection reset by peer
```

On the new server, it looks like this:

```
# iperf3 -c us.1sys1.com -P 4
iperf3: error - unable to send control message: Bad file descriptor

# iperf3 -c us.1sys1.com -P 4 -R
iperf3: error - unable to send control message: Bad file descriptor
```

I disabled the firewall on both servers during the test.

here is my ip setup:

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:50:99:fa:0b:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp35s0
    inet <correct public ip>/8 brd 74.255.255.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 <correct ipv6>/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:50:99:fa:0b:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp36s0
4: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:ca:80:8e:6a:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp3s0f0u14u3c2
```

my network setup:

```
# nmcli -f TYPE,FILENAME,NAME conn
TYPE      FILENAME                                                                NAME
ethernet  /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth0.nmconnection                eth0
loopback  /run/NetworkManager/system-connections/lo.nmconnection                  lo
ethernet  /run/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 1.nmconnection  Wired connection 1
ethernet  /run/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 2.nmconnection  Wired connection 2
```

The above eth0.nmconnection file:

```
[connection]
id=eth0
uuid=7086daf5-df0c-46f9-b03d-99bfec25983f
type=ethernet
interface-name=eth0
timestamp=1711515608

[ethernet]

[ipv4]
address1=<my correct ip>/8,10.255.255.1
dns=212.227.123.16;212.227.123.17;
dhcp-hostname=C587AE
method=manual

[ipv6]
method=ignore

[proxy]
```

Any idea what I could be looking for to debug would be highly appreciated. What other tests can I do? what network configs do I need to look at?

thanks!

Comment: Are the hosts on the same network? Are there routers? What is the routing tables? How far do the packets get?

Comment: @GregAskew I do not know. How can find out? I have to assume that the error is on my side, but what setting on my side could be causing so specific outages?